# Class overloading in Java - is it possible?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, syntax

Instead of using traditional polymorphism `... extends LinkedList<T>`, **is there a way to overload on a class such as String, List or a custom MyClass class, in Java?**.

```
theList.doRandomShuffle(123); or theList.persistOnFile("fileName");
```

Mixing C code to achieve this is on the table if possible. Any further suggestions will be useful.

UPDATE: OK. String class was not a good example. The purpose was to extend a class without declaring a new list `MyList extends LinkedList<T>` or creating a utility class for the wanted function. I am eliminating two possibilities of extension to achieve and asking if there is more option even if it is hardcore.

**The reason beyond this is to question if possible to extend classes especially for jar libraries without adapting to the new extended classes of LinkedList impl. whatsoever. I am really disappointed by the community that no one knows for sure, thinks even questioning should be out of the box**

Comment: Can you give a better example? Right now I take it that you're trying to add a method to an already defined class, which is something that cannot be done in Java (well, it *can*, but that would be a breach of Java's terms and conditions of use).

Comment: Overloading *is* a form of polymorphism. Aside from the fact that you can't extend String your question remains obscure.

Comment: @Vulcan you seem to know how. how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you cannot add a method to an already defined class such as String.  However, if the class is not `final`, you can extend it to create custom methods.

(Technically, you can add methods to defined classes, but it's a hassle and would be a breach of Java's terms and conditions of use.)

Comment: Research the use of the "Xbootclasspath/p:" JVM option.  Another approach is to use bytecode modification at runtime but that's more work and more likely to break than the former.  Just remember, don't use these methods to break Java's EULA ;)

Comment: excellent! thank you so much for your valuable answer. that is exactly what i needed :) With this solution, I can even override and overload class fields, and methods. http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2010/02/replacing-and-patching-java-application-and-core-classes/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override String behavior because the class is final. You can, of course, do this with a custom class. Can you be more specific on exactly what you're trying to do?

there is no way to make either of your example statements

String.doFunyStuff(123); 
 "doFunny".onMe(1);

legal in java.

Answer (score 0):

Class String is a final class,you can't extend it.

Answer (score 0):

No, Java doesn't support anything like [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) in C#. The best you can do is define a static method that takes a `String` as an argument and then operates on it, possibly returning a `String`. Since `String` is an [immutable class](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29), there shouldn't be a difference from what you're trying to achieve aside from syntax.

Comment: +1 - for the interesting info about C#

Comment: the answer was leading into the wrong way. your solution was to address something which was never asked at the first place.

Comment: @HayatiGuvence - With respect, I think it's kind of a silly reason for a downvote. I wrote the answer *before* your update, so I assumed you meant strictly for `String`. Not only is `String` `final` so it can't be extended, you said "Instead of using traditional polymorphism" - this led me to reference C#'s extension methods as what you were probably envisioning, explain that the language doesn't support such a thing, and offer an alternative.

Comment: @PaulBellora - I asked "instead of polymorphism is there a way to overload on a class such as String or a custom MyClass class." Where "overload a class" here is not common in polymorphism, not even any where. I never said strictly anything about "String". It was an example using the english form "such as". Nevertheless, your answer was incorrect by saying it was not even possible by failing to comprehend the issue from the beginning, yet misleading. however, there was an answer even if it is String. Next time, you read the question properly and leave an answer if you know it for sure.

Comment: @HayatiGuvence - You are wrong.  In a number of respects.  1) C#'s extension mechanism is not polymorphism. 2) Paul's assumption that you were talking about `final` types is reasonable, given your **original** Question.  3) If you are going to use non-standard terminology like "overload a class", then Answers that use a different interpretation to yours are not incorrect. 4) Down-voting Answers to your own questions is (IMO) rude ... and counter productive. 5) *" Next time ..."* - that comment is offensive, IMO.

Comment: @All Quality vs Quantity. I choose quality.